# Step to translate Joomla component

Tags: components, joomla2.5, translation

I've created an administrator component for Joomla 2.5 recently (in French), and not knowing how to proceed to translate it in English and German, I was wondering if someone could help me understanding the process.

Indeed, I think I understood that I need to format my strings such as :

```
JText::_( 'mystring' )
```

Then that I create .ini files, but I don't know where to create them, what they should contain, if it exists a tool like PoEdit that could suit etc. So if you have any idea how I should proceed...

Thank's guys !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the "language" directory at the root of your website, you create the directories and files :

```
administration/language/en-GB/en-GB.com_yourcomponentname.ini
administration/language/fr-FR/fr-FR.com_yourcomponentname.ini
administration/language/de-DE/de-DE.com_yourcomponentname.ini
```

You translate each of them. I am not sure, you need a tool to do that.

And I don't know if it exists a PoEdit plugin to help you to do that too...

Your ini files look like the others that already exist in the language directories :

```
COM_ADMIN="Informations système"
COM_ADMIN_ALPHABETICAL_INDEX="Index alphabétique"
COM_ADMIN_CACHE_DIRECTORY="(Répertoire cache)"
```

Then in your views, to call a translated string :

```
JText::_( 'COM_ADMIN' )
```

This function will look for the value of COM_ADMIN in the ini file.

The loaded ini file will be the language the user has chosen, and if a translation doesn't exist, then it will load the value of the default language (chosen in administration panel).

Then if this key doesn't exist in any of these ini file, they the key is displayed.

To package your archive :

In install.xml, add these lines :

```
<administration>
    <!-- Directory and file stuff -->

    <languages folder="language/admin">
        <language tag="en-GB">en-GB/en-GB.com_yourcomponentname.ini</language>
        <language tag="fr-FR">fr-FR/fr-FR.com_yourcomponentname.ini</language>
        <language tag="de-DE">de-DE/de-DE.com_yourcomponentname.ini</language>
    </languages>
</administration>
```

And add the translation files in the language/admin directory.

Comment: Thanks it's really clear, but I developed a component so that people can install it, not only for my own use. So I guess I can't create folders at the root of my website since they will not be created in other installations except mine...

Comment: Ok, edit your post then to add this information. When I have to create a component to export, I use http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/tools/webbased-tools/7627

Comment: Why I would use your software I already developed my component ? I only need to add translation files inside if possible, that's all.

Comment: Ok, I thought you haven't created any component archive. Then, you have to add at the root of your component archive the directories and files I told you : /language/admin/fr-FR . I think it is enough.

Comment: Edit : add archive informations in main post ( files and install.xml )